# Response Exchange EWS

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

How can I get a response after I make a new appointment? An OK response or Not OK and the reason for it..?

After the authentication this is my code for creating the appointment

```
            DateTime bookingStart = new DateTime(2017, 6, 14, 14, 0, 0);
        DateTime bookingEnd = bookingStart.AddHours(2);
        Booking booking = new Booking()
        {
            Subject = "BookingTest",
            Start = bookingStart,
            End = bookingEnd,
            Room = "xxx.room@dummy.be",
            Person = "person@dummy.be"
        };
        //Meetingrequest aanmaken
        var request = new Appointment(service)
        {
            Subject = booking.Subject,
            Start = booking.Start,
            End = booking.End,
            Location = booking.Room
        };
        //Aanhangen wie wilt meedoen
        request.RequiredAttendees.Add(booking.Person);
        request.RequiredAttendees.Add(booking.Room);

        ServiceResponse response = service.CreateItems()

        request.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendOnlyToAll);
```

But this doesn't give me an object back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you save this appointment, the meeting item will get a unique identifier.

```
request.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendOnlyToAll);
var id = request.Id.UniqueId;
```

Save the identifier, later on, you can use this identifier to track the meeting response like this

```
Appointment meeting = Appointment.Bind(service, new ItemId(id));
for (int i = 0; i < meeting.RequiredAttendees.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Required attendee - " + meeting.RequiredAttendees[i].Address + ": " + meeting.RequiredAttendees[i].ResponseType.Value.ToString());
}
```

Reference: [Tracking meeting responses by using the EWS Managed API 2.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633669(v=exchg.80).aspx)

Comment: Wait for the attendees to click "OK/Not OK". You can't run this _immediately_ after sending out the invitation.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't have it yet to complete what I need. I can do what you say and I get the id , but how can I see for example that the room is busy on the same time?